# How would I enable browser spell check in TinyMCE Richtext editor when using with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, tinymce, spell-checking, spelling

I am using TinyMCE text editor for my application with angularjs. I need to enable to browser's spell check functionality.
Since it's a text area, it should by default enable the spell check as it works with a normal textarea, but it doesn't work.
I am using [ui-tinymce](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce) for my application to get tinymce plugin to work.

Does anyone know what I can do to achieve spell check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could figure it out myself.
What we can do is to have an option set when initializing the tinymce.
Essentially, in tinymce-ui.js,
add

```
browser_spellcheck : true
```

along with other options.
So the code will look like:

```
options = {
    .
    .
    mode: 'exact',
    browser_spellcheck : true,
    elements: attrs.id
};

angular.extend(options, uiTinymceConfig, expression);
    setTimeout(function () {
    tinymce.init(options);
});
```